# Detect Orientation of Video and auto rotate if needed

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, orientation, rotation

I am looking to see if its possible to get the device orientation of a video to check and see if its needs to be rotated in PHP with ffmpeg.

Is this even possible? I have done it easy enough with images, but I have not found anything so far to help with this.

Comment: Are you talking about getting the aspect ratio of the movie, or the orientation of the display device itself (e.g. landscape/portrait for phones)

Comment: The device orientation. So that I can flip the video if needed

Comment: Thats what I thought when I posted the answer below (I just undeleted it).  Hope it helps.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't do this server side.

Comment: Sorry I think I haven't not explained the question right. I don't want to detect the orientation of the device playing the video, but the orientation of the device that took the video. The problem I am trying to solve is some video are uploaded and they are sideways. I want to detect if the video needs to be rotated to show upright. I did this with images being uploaded by getting the device orientation info form the image. I just can't seem to figure it out for videos.

Comment: Hey Josh, I'm trying to solve the same problem. MediaInfo (http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) CLI will get you this info, but not in the most usable manner. Run "mediainfo -f <filename> | grep Rotation

Answer (score 0):

Device orientation is a client side property, and PHP is strictly server-side.  Quickly googling led me to [this page](http://www.engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/2008/06/19/tutorial-building-a-website-for-the-iphone/), which has an example for the iPhone.  The author offers this function, which is called on page load:

```
function updateOrientation(){  
    var contentType = "show_";  
    switch(window.orientation){  
        case 0:  
            contentType += "normal";  
            break;  

        case -90:  
            contentType += "right";  
            break;  

        case 90:  
            contentType += "left";  
            break;  

        case 180:  
            contentType += "flipped";  
            break;  
    }  
    document.getElementById("page_wrapper").setAttribute("class", contentType);  
}
```

CSS is defined to handle styling for `.show_normal`, `.show_right`, `.show_left` and `.show_flipped`

```
.show_normal,  
.show_flipped{  
   width:320px;  
}  
.show_left,  
.show_right{  
    width:480px;  
}
```

If you need the value for the orientation in PHP, you can send the value of `window.orientation` to a script via AJAX.  There is also an event: `window.onorientationchange` that gets fired whenever the orientation changes.  I believe both of those properties on the window are available for both iPhone and Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
exiftool -Rotation <filename>
```