# PHP "exec" cannot access filenames which have national Danish characters?

Tags: php, character-encoding, centos, mediainfo

I am creating a web page on my CentOS server, where I want to traverse all my photos and videos and then show them on my page. However then it seems that when the files have our Danish national characters included, like `æøåÆØÅ`, then my `exec` command cannot access the file - and I need the `exec` command as I need `mediainfo` to show-and-tell the format and other details of the file (video, audio or image).

Let's assume I have this data and array that I am traversing (3 files):

```
$folder = "!My Folder"; // parent folder has a special char

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => !file #2.jpg
            [descr] => File with special chars, but no national chars

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [filename] => file with Danish æøå.jpg
            [descr] => File with Danish chars, but no special chars
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [filename] => file with no special.jpg
            [descr] => File with nothing special
        )
)
```

I am then reading the `mediainfo` info from PHP like this:

```
$param = escapeshellarg("$folder/$filename"); // escape file argument
exec("mediainfo $param", $outputArray); // store line-by-line output in an array
```

This works fine for file `[0]` and `[2]` (I get a populated array), but `[1]` just returns an empty array from the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

As a note then I am able to use `mediainfo` directly on the server and doing this *will* work fine and return detailed data:

```
[usr@srv !My Folder]# mediainfo file\ with\ Danish\ æøå.jpg
```

So it seems to be the `exec` that has some problems with this?

I am using PHP 8.1 and I have no problem accessing or storing files on my server, via Samba, with these Danish characters.

An alternative solution would be to rename the files with these characters, but ideally I hope to avoid doing that as it is kind of "destructive" (messing with the original files).

Does anyone have a good idea how to access those files via `exec`?

**### UPDATE 1 - BUT STILL NO SOLUTION ###**

Just to make it crystal clear and to "prove" this is something related to `exec` then I refer to the answer from @CBroe below and adding one additional line to set the locale character encoding in PHP, `setlocale` + outputting the `exec` command:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
$param = escapeshellarg("$folder/$filename");
exec("mediainfo $param", $outputArray);
echo "mediainfo $param";
```

The `echo` will output this (and an empty array):

> mediainfo '/server/original/!My Folder/file with Danish æøå.jpg'

But if I run this exact same command directly on my server, `mediainfo '/server/original/!My Folder/file with Danish æøå.jpg'` then it will show me the media info for the file:

[image]

I also believe that this is some character encoding issue, but yet I do not know how to solve it ;-)

**### UPDATE 2 - BUT STILL NO SOLUTION ###**

As suggested below, then I also did try using `putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8')`, but for me that didn't help. I also tried using `shell_exec()` instead of `exec()` - same result and it did not help.

```
putenv("LANG=en_US.UTF-8");

$folder = "!My Folder"; // parent folder has a special char
$filename = "file with Danish æøå.jpg";

$param = escapeshellarg("$folder/$filename");
$output = shell_exec("mediainfo $param");
$outputArray = explode("\n",$output);
print_r($outputArray);
```

This will result in an array with two empty values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late, but i stumbled across this today (pretty much the same, filename from `glob()` function and working further). This is not a problem of `exec()` but of the environment that `mediainfo` uses.

If you use UTF-8 filenames, it is essential to set the LANG environment correctly.

```
putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8');
```

worked for me.

Comment: I tested this and it did not make any difference for me. Even I would state, that this is the exact same thing I already tried with `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");`

Comment: `setlocale()` doesn't make a difference here, but `putenv()` does (i use `shell_exec()` or backticks to make `mediainfo` happy though).

Answer (score -1):

Testing `echo escapeshellarg("file with Danish æøå.jpg");` on https://3v4l.org/FEWfI only gives me `'file with Danish .jpg'` as result.

Checking the user comments for the function, there is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php#99213:

> When escapeshellarg() was stripping my non-ASCII characters from a UTF-8 string, adding the following fixed the problem:
>
> ```
> <?php
> setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
> ?>
> ```

That indeed appears to fix the problem, https://3v4l.org/1DfpF - result now is `'file with Danish æøå.jpg'`

Comment: `echo` may show the Danish chars but still `exec` returns an empty array when adding `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");` just before I set the `$param` variable - so no fix as I see it, sorry :-)

Comment: So what do you get when you do an `echo "mediainfo $param"`? Does that look the same as the working version you enter directly via console?

Comment: Yes, when echoing the command to the web page and copying it to the CentOS shell, then it works fine in the shell and it will show detailed info from `mediainfo` for the file with Danish chars.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with different character encodings in some place. Is your page using UTF-8? Where did you get the array of file data from, was that read directly from the file system?

Comment: My web page is in UTF-8 and the files array is coming directly from a `scandir`.